# How to implement Axios with Vus.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios

How can I implement Axios? I went through the documentation but still not clear, thank you in advance, something to do with the API request from the weather site I presume

I only included the script part I hope that would be enough.
My question is not debugging but how to simply replace the request part using axios.

```html
<script>
  export default {
    name: 'app',
    data() {
      return {
        api_key: 'f401be24a6ae97c3177533197510126c',
        url_base: 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/',
        query: '',
        weather: {}

      }
    },
    methods: {
      fetchWeather(e) {
        if (e.key == "Enter") {
          fetch(`${this.url_base}weather?q=${this.query}&units=metric&APPID=${this.api_key}`)
            .then(res => {
              return res.json();
            }).then(this.setResults);
        }
      },
      setResults(results) {
        this.weather = results;
      },
      dateCreator() {
        let dates = new Date();
        let months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
        let days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
        let day = days[dates.getDay()];
        let date = dates.getDate();
        let month = months[dates.getMonth()];
        let year = dates.getFullYear();
        return `${day} ${date} ${month} ${year}`;
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like following snippet:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data(){
    return {
      api_key :'f401be24a6ae97c3177533197510126c',
      url_base: 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/',
      query:'',
      weather:{}

    }
  },
  methods: {
  async fetchWeather () {
      //if (e.key == "Enter") {
        await axios(`${this.url_base}weather?q=${this.query}&units=metric&APPID=${this.api_key}`)
          .then(res => this.weather = res.data);
      //}
    },
    dateCreator () {
      let dates = new Date();
      let months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
      let days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
      let day = days[dates.getDay()];
      let date = dates.getDate();
      let month = months[dates.getMonth()];
      let year = dates.getFullYear();
      return `${day} ${date} ${month} ${year}`;
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    if(this.query) this.fetchWeather()
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.22.0/axios.min.js" integrity="sha512-m2ssMAtdCEYGWXQ8hXVG4Q39uKYtbfaJL5QMTbhl2kc6vYyubrKHhr6aLLXW4ITeXSywQLn1AhsAaqrJl8Acfg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<div id="app">
  <label>City name</label>
  <input v-model="query" />
  <button @click.prevent="fetchWeather">Show weather<button>
  <p>{{ weather }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for this, that is perfect, but i NEED to use Axios library

Comment: Take a look now I updated answer, you need to npm install axios, then import axios in component, then call axios